# Position independent code: what is the difference at compile time?

Tags: dynamic-linking, linker, compiler-construction, dynamic-loading

Reading through the [libtool docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Creating-object-files) I wondered why we need to tell the compiler to produce position independent code. After all, the object file which is produced does not yet know where in address space it will be linked at, so one single object file should be position independent at all times, shouldn't it? And further, to produce shared object libs, wouldn't that simply mean baking together all the object files which make out that lib and possibly setting all relative references which have become "intern" to the baked-together lib, while leaving all other references (absolute and relative) to be filled out later by the linker-loader? Why is this a concern also for the compiler?

Comment: Possibly more ontopic on SO. Is this really unix-specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wondered why we need to tell the compiler to produce position independent code.After all, the object file which is produced does not yet know where in address space it will be linked at, so one single object file should be position independent at all times, shouldn't it?

When you tell your compiler to produce position independent code(PIC), it differs entirely from the compiler which produce non-PIC, mostly regarding function and data access. The reason to use PIC is to avoid buffer overrun or code overwrite which occurs when someone inputs few lines of code into your application address space mostly written in low-level languages like C/C++ because by default C/C++ don't check for bounds.

It uses an indirect method to access the data and functions with the help of a table called "Global Offset Table"(GOT). This GOT is usually located in Special Machine Register. The main benefit to use this table is that the generation of code will be independent of actual load address. At the run time it will update the offsets in the table depending on the current load address of needed libraries.

When the compiler produce an object file (.lo in PIC) it loads the object at random address without modification and even if the load address of an object is fixed for some ABI, it will load the each required libraries at random address.The object file which is produced doesn't know where in address space it will be linked at, well that is exactly PIC wants to do so that no linking address is fixed which might compromise the application security if an attacker finds that address.

> And further, to produce shared object libs, wouldn't that simply mean baking together all the object files which make out that lib and possibly setting all relative references which have become "intern" to the baked-together lib, while leaving all other references (absolute and relative) to be filled out later by the linker-loader? Why is this a concern also for the compiler?

In case of shared library, libtool when sees the 'PIC' flag set in the preprocessor it automatically build the object file for shared libraries. They haven't became "intern" because shared libraries could be located anywhere in process memory layout and they are accessed indirectly by some flags set when building.

Wiki:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code

Gentoo: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Hardened

Comment: Ok, I think I know now, where I missed the point of shared libs: shared lib foolib.so can appear at address X for one process and at address Y for another process, is that right?

Comment: Actually each process has its own virtual address space, so if the shared library like foolib.so is build with PIC then it can be anywhere within the processes virtual address space.

Comment: Shouldn't we say: it MUST be built with PIC, because otherwise it could collide with code from the process which is actually trying to use the lib?

Comment: Yes, it should be built with PIC as libtool recommends.Though in theory you could build a shared library without PIC. But the whole purpose of having shared library in a system is to make the use of shared library dynamic because a programmer/compiler in advance doesn't have the knowledge that where the required/needed shared library could be located, and that is where PIC is useful it provides location in-dependency.Regarding collision of addresses: with PIC same library code can be loaded in each program address space so that it won't overlap any other uses of memory.